# How can I use curl to upload a file using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl

I want to upload a file together with some information(e.g. package_type) with curl

in my `submission` model:

```
has_attached_file :package
```

What I tried:

```
curl -d "submission[package_type]=type1&submission[package]=@/home/ubuntu/Downloads/test.zip" http://localhost:3000/restapi.json
```

If I leave out the file object, it works(a entry will be inserted into the database)

But I specify the file like above, it gives me an error:

```
No handler found for "@/home/ubuntu/Downloads/test.zip"
```

**Update**:

I just found that that I should use the `-F` option in curl, but in that case the file information cannot be recorded, is there anyway to include both the file object and file info? Maybe something like `curl -d -F` ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and ended up setting the content-type to multipart/form-data instead of dealing with base64 encoding issues when posting to my REST API. Here is an example which includes headers for auth:

```
curl -v -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -H "X-User-Email: <email>" -H "X-User-Token: <token>" -X POST -i -F submission[package_type]=type1 -F submission[image_attributes][image]=@f117.jpg http://localhost:3000/api/v1/submissions
```